# How to wait for a closed port in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I made a device to track the discharge voltage of a battery using INA219 sensor and Arduino, the information gathered by Arduino then send to the Raspberry pi in Serial communication, and with aim of python coding and matplotlib, drawnow modules, the output will get plotted real-time on an LCD,
I've set a watchdog function for Arduino to get reset if it freezes anyhow, but meanwhile, how can I use the pyserial module to wait for a closed port to open again and not get terminated?
in the following you can see my python code:

```
import serial
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator
from matplotlib.dates import AutoDateLocator, AutoDateFormatter
from drawnow import *
#import csv

Voltage_0 = [0]
Current_0 = [0]
ResInt_0 = [0]
Power_0 = [0]
Voltage_1 = [0]
Current_1 = [0]
ResInt_1 = [0]
Power_1 = [0]
Voltage_4 = [0]
Current_4 = [0]
ResInt_4 = [0]
Power_4 = [0]
Voltage_5 = [0]
Current_5 = [0]
ResInt_5 = [0]
Power_5 = [0]
Time = []
StartTime = 0
PlotTime = 0
PresentTime = 0
i = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=1)
plt.ion()
StartTime = datetime.now()
h = StartTime.hour
m = StartTime.minute
s = StartTime.second
PresentTime = StartTime + timedelta(seconds=5)
PlotTime = PresentTime - timedelta(hours= h,minutes= m, seconds= s)
Time.append(PlotTime)

def CreatePlot():
    plt.suptitle('Type AA Battery Discharge Window')

    ax0 = plt.subplot(2,2,1)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.plot(Time, Voltage_0,'#ff0400', label='V0')
    ax0.set(xlabel='Time', ylabel='Voltage')
    plt.legend(loc='upper center')
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05, hspace=0.07)
    locator = AutoDateLocator()
    ax0.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
    formatter = AutoDateFormatter(locator)
    ax0.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
    ax0.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
    plt.ylim(0,1.7)
    ax0.label_outer()

    ax1 = plt.subplot(2,2,2)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.plot(Time, Voltage_1,'#ffaa00', label='V1')
    ax1.set(xlabel='Time', ylabel='Voltage')
    plt.legend(loc='upper center')
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05, hspace=0.07)
    locator = AutoDateLocator()
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
    formatter = AutoDateFormatter(locator)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
    ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
    plt.ylim(0,1.7)
    ax1.label_outer()

    ax2 = plt.subplot(2,2,3)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.plot(Time,Voltage_4, '#fff200', label='V4')
    ax2.set(xlabel='Time', ylabel='Voltage')
    plt.legend(loc='upper center')
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05, hspace=0.07)
    locator = AutoDateLocator()
    ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
    formatter = AutoDateFormatter(locator)
    ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
    ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
    plt.ylim(0,1.7)
    ax2.label_outer()

    ax3 = plt.subplot(2,2,4)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.plot(Time,Voltage_5, '#0af219', label='V5')
    ax3.set(xlabel='Time', ylabel='Voltage')
    plt.legend(loc='upper center')
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05, hspace=0.07)
    locator = AutoDateLocator()
    ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
    formatter = AutoDateFormatter(locator)
    ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
    ax3.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
    plt.ylim(0,1.7)
    ax3.label_outer()

while True:
    if arduino.in_waiting > 0:
        arduinoString = arduino.readline().decode('UTF-8').rstrip()
        PresentTime = datetime.now()
        dataArray = arduinoString.split(',')

        vol_0 = float( dataArray[0])
        cur_0 = float( dataArray[1])
        res_0 = float( dataArray[2])
        pow_0 = float( dataArray[3])
        Voltage_0.append(vol_0)
        Current_0.append(cur_0)
        ResInt_0.append(res_0)
        Power_0.append(pow_0)

        vol_1 = float( dataArray[4])
        cur_1 = float( dataArray[5])
        res_1 = float( dataArray[6])
        pow_1 = float( dataArray[7])
        Voltage_1.append(vol_1)
        Current_1.append(cur_1)
        ResInt_1.append(res_1)
        Power_1.append(pow_1)

        vol_4 = float( dataArray[8])
        cur_4 = float( dataArray[9])
        res_4 = float( dataArray[10])
        pow_4 = float( dataArray[11])
        Voltage_4.append(vol_4)
        Current_4.append(cur_4)
        ResInt_4.append(res_4)
        Power_4.append(pow_4)

        vol_5 = float( dataArray[12])
        cur_5 = float( dataArray[13])
        res_5 = float( dataArray[14])
        pow_5 = float( dataArray[15])
        Voltage_5.append(vol_5)
        Current_5.append(cur_5)
        ResInt_5.append(res_5)
        Power_5.append(pow_5)

        ArdTime = float( dataArray[16])

        PlotTime = PresentTime - timedelta(hours= h,minutes= m, seconds= s)
        Time.append(PlotTime)

        with open('AA_OUTPUT.csv', 'a') as f:
            if i==0:
                f.write('Time,Voltage_0 (V),Current_0 (mA), Internal Resistance_0 (mohm), Power_0 (mW),'
                    'Voltage_1 (V),Current_1 (mA), Internal Resistance_1 (mohm), Power_1 (mW),'
                    'Voltage_4 (V),Current_4 (mA), Internal Resistance_4 (mohm), Power_4 (mW),'
                    'Voltage_5 (V),Current_5 (mA), Internal Resistance_5 (mohm), Power_5 (mW)\n')
                f.write('{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}\n'.format(ArdTime,
                    Voltage_0[-1],Current_0[-1],ResInt_0[-1],Power_0[-1],
                    Voltage_1[-1],Current_1[-1],ResInt_1[-1],Power_1[-1],
                    Voltage_4[-1],Current_4[-1],ResInt_4[-1],Power_4[-1],
                    Voltage_5[-1],Current_5[-1],ResInt_5[-1],Power_5[-1])) #for Python2 users
                i+=1
            else:
                #f.write(f'{PlotTime},{vol_0},{cur_0},{res_0},{pow_0},{vol_1},{cur_1},{res_1},
                    # {pow_1},{vol_4},{cur_4},{res_4},{pow_4},{vol_5},{cur_5},{res_5},{pow_5}\n') #for Python3 users
                f.write('{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}\n'.format(ArdTime,
                    Voltage_0[-1],Current_0[-1],ResInt_0[-1],Power_0[-1],
                    Voltage_1[-1],Current_1[-1],ResInt_1[-1],Power_1[-1],
                    Voltage_4[-1],Current_4[-1],ResInt_4[-1],Power_4[-1],
                    Voltage_5[-1],Current_5[-1],ResInt_5[-1],Power_5[-1])) #for Python2 users
    drawnow(CreatePlot)
    plt.pause(0.0001)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_open` from the pySerial module can be used to retrieve it's current status.

```
while True:
    if arduino.is_open:
        if arduino.in_waiting > 0:
            # rest of your code
        drawnow(CreatePlot)
        plt.pause(0.0001)
    else:
        arduino.open()
```

Comment: @farzadlatifeh happy to help! please mark as solved if you're all set =]

Comment: it's been checked